# browserHistory.push not rerender view when called inside onEnter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router v2.8.1. I noticed that `browserHistory.push` will not cause a rendering of the view when called inside onEnter. The URL will change as expected tho.

Also, It works perfectly fine when called anywhere else.

I understand onEnter callback gets a 'replace' method which can be used to achieve redirect.

But I am curious why `browserHistory.push()` does not work?

--update code--

```
function authRequired () {
  browserHistory.push("/login")
}

export default(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/login" component={LoginView} />
    <Route path="/" component={Main} onEnter={authRequired}>
      <IndexRedirect to="/main" />
      <Route path="main" component={MainView} />
      <Route path="minor" component={MinorView} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
);
```

Comment: can you show the code your are using